# analytic function which is zero on a segment of a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [on the boundary of analytic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24429/on-the-boundary-of-analytic-functions)

I was thinking of a problem I will feel happy if you
give hint to solve this. Suppose I have a function $f$ that is analytic
on the unit disk $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ that extends continuously to $\overline{D}$. If $f$ is identically zero on some segment of of the boundary,
is it then true that $f$ is identically zero on the entire boundary?

I know that analytic functions that are zero at an
accumulation point inside the domain of analyticity are identically
zero throughout the entire domain, but I don't know what (if anything)
can be said if something similar occurs on the boundary of the domain.

Comment: Dear rita, in fact, such a function is identically zero. Since this question has already been asked (and answered, quite nicely!) on this website, I've closed it. Please see the link above.

Comment: Hum, isn't this almost a word-for-word copy of the duplicate question listed above?