# Limits are constant on an arc implies analytic function $f(z)$ is constant on the open unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)$ is  analytic on the open unit disk $\{|z| < 1 \}$. Assume that $\lim_{z\to t} f(z) = c$ for all $t$ on an arc $\{e^{i\theta}: \theta \in (a,b)\}$ and some constant $c$. How to proof $f(z)$ is constant on the open unit disk?

I have read solutions to this question: [function constant on arc is constant on boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258619/function-constant-on-arc-is-constant-on-boundary), but it assume $f(z)$ is continuous up to the boundary of the disk. Without the condition, we cannot use Cauchy integral theorem for $f(z)$, and I have no idea how I can associate the boundary with the interior.

Comment: But $f(z)$ need not to be bound on the open disk, $f(z)$ at the boundary is not well-defined.

Comment: See the [Luzin-Privalov theorems](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Luzin-Privalov_theorems)