# Does a bounded continuous function map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences?

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I only ever see the example of $f:(0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$as that of a continuous function that does not map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.

Are there examples of bounded continuous functions that do not map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences?  I am not looking for wild topologies here, but more so if this is possible for, say, a holomorphic function on the unit disk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=\sin\frac1x$ on $(0,1]$. For the disk you just need a bounded holomorphic function on the disk that's discontinuous on the boundary. Such functions do exist, as answers to [Continuous Extension of a Bounded Holomorphic Function on the unit disk?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58723/continuous-extension-of-a-bounded-holomorphic-function-on-the-unit-disk) show, but it's harder to produce an explicit example.

Answer (score 3):

$\sin(1/x)$ maps the sequence $x_n=\frac1n$ to $\sin(n)$ which is definitely not Cauchy.