# Are bounded analytic functions on the unit disk continuous on the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, analyticity, hardy-spaces

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic on the open disk $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$.
Moreover, let $f$ be bounded on the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$, i.e.
$$ \sup_{\varphi \in [0,2\pi]} |f(e^{i\varphi})| < \infty $$
(This class of functions is sometimes called $H^\infty$).

My question regards the boundary function $\tilde{f}(\varphi) := \lim_{r \rightarrow 1} f(r e^{i\varphi})$. Is it continuous?

Comment: What do you take as boundary values? The radial limits?

Comment: yes - edited the the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not true in general that a bounded holomorphic function on the unit disk extends continuously to the boundary. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6210/1726) by Jonas Meyer explains how to construct such a function explicitly using [Blaschke products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product).

However, if you believe the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem), there is a quick geometric way to construct a counterexample.  Consider the following closed subset of the plane:

[image]

This is a variant of the famous [topologist's since curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve), and consists of the graph of $y = \sin(\pi/x)$ for $0<x<1$ together with the line segment from $(0,-1)$ to $(0,1)$ and a curve from the point $(0,0)$ to the point $(1,0)$.

Let $U$ be the interior region, i.e. bounded component of the complement of this closed set.  Then $U$ is open and simply connected, so there exists a Riemann map $f\colon\mathbb{D} \to U$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk.  The function $f$ is holomorphic and bounded, but $f$ cannot extend continuously to the boundary of the disk, since the boundary of $U$ isn't a continuous image of a circle.

Comment: In this example it is easy to see that the radial limit function is discontinuous, but for the general question I would just add that continuity of the radial limit function does not trivially imply continuity of the function on the closed disk. It is true, though, by the Luzin-Privalov theorems.

Comment: Also, there is a function $(1+z)^{i}$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. It is bounded in the unit disk, without limit at $z=-1$.