# Zeros on the boundary of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is analytic in $\{z\in \mathbb{C}, \Im z>0\}$, and continuous in  $\{z\in \mathbb{C}, \Im z\ge 0\}$. I'm curious about the structure of the set 
$$
E=\{z\in \mathbb{R},~~ f(z)=0\}
$$
When restrict $f$ on the real line, it's not analytic, so $E$ may not be discrete.

**My question:** Is there an example such that the set $E$ contains uncountable points (such as a cantor set)?

Is it true that $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ is of measure $0$?

Comment: Remark.  Can we get an example with a dense set of zeros on the boundary?  The set of zeros of a continuous function must be a $G_\delta$-set, so if it is dense then it is uncountable by the Baire category theorem.

Comment: @GEdgar No, the zero set must be closed and nowhere dense.

Comment: Yes, exactly the closed measure zero sets $E$ are possible as zero sets. This is classical, but requires some machinery. See for example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6208/isolated-zeros-on-closure-of-a-domain