# Are polynomials dense in $H^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hardy-spaces

Let $H^\infty(D)=\{f:D\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}: f \;\text{is bounded and analytic on}\; {D}\}$ where $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$. Are the polynomials dense in $H^\infty(D)$? I know that they are dense in  other Hardy spaces $H^p(D)$ for $0<p<\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, polynomials are not dense in $H^\infty(D)$. The uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials (or, more generally, uniformly continuous functions) is always uniformly continuous and thus extends continously to $\bar D$. The set of bounded analytic functions on $D$ with continuous extension to $\bar D$ is the [disk algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_algebra) $A(D)$, and polynomials are indeed dense in $A(D)$ by [Mergelyan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergelyan%27s_theorem).

However, $A(D)$ is a proper subspace of $H^\infty(D)$ as Jonas Meyer explains in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6208/isolated-zeros-on-closure-of-a-domain/6210#6210) answer. For a more explicit example, take $f(z)=\exp(\frac{z+1}{z-1})$. This function is bounded and analytic on $D$, but for every $w\in D$ one can find a sequence $(z_n)$ in $D$ converging to $1$ such that $f(z_n)\to w$.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up after a long time, but couldn't come up with a proof myself. Are the polynomials WOT-dense in $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$?